# Why does this simple square root fail in Python

Tags: python

```
4**(1/2) = 1
```

It's giving 1, it is suppose to be 2. If i replace the 1/2 with 0.5 it would work

Answer (score 1):

1/2 gives integer result of 0, So `4**0 = 1`

try `1.0/2`

```
>>> 4**(1/2)
1
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 4**(1.0/2)
2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are integers, so 1/2=0 Hence you have 4**0 which is indeed 1. I don't know python at all, but from knowledge of other languages I suspect you need something like 1.0/2.0 to get 0.5

Answer (score 0):

`1/2` is evaluated as an integral, so it gives `0`. 0.5 is a float, so that works. What you want to do is add a dot either the one or the 2

```
1./2 = 0.5
```